# How can the OPTIM function works properly?

Tags: r

Here, my function nd works properly but when I used that in OPTIM function it gives error.
What is my mistake? Codes are

```
ta=c(2.0, 4.0);       
n=500;                

x=runif(n);        

TT=rexp(n,1);       
D=matrix(0,n,1);        

for (j in 1:n) {
D[j]=ifelse(TT[j]>x[j],1,0)
}

xt=matrix(0,length(ta),1);
for (ii in 1:length(ta)) {
 xt[ii]=sum(I(TT<ta[ii])*D)      
}

nd<- function(params) {
tta=c(params[1],params[2]);
ss1=0;

ss1=xt[1]*log(xt[1]/sum(pmin(TT,tta[1])))+(xt[2]-xt[1])*log((xt[2]-xt[1])/sum((pmin(TT,tta[2])-tta[1])*I(TT>tta[1])))+(sum(D)-xt[2])*log((sum(D)-xt[2])/sum((TT-tta[2])*I(TT>tta[2])));
ll=-ss1;

return (ll)  
 }


nn<-optim(par=c(0.5,2.5),fn=nd, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0.01,2.01), upper=c(3.99, 9.99));
```

I found the following error;

Error in optim(par = c(0.5, 2.5), fn = nd, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0.01,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Comment: Could you give the error message, and a little more detail about where it occurs?

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't be criticizing someone for posting code that doesn't throw an error, but using `ifelse` inside a `for` loop is hard to view. Furthermore you should be posting the error message, which in this case suggests you are getting Inf results. Generally checking for division by zero is the first step. "Error in optim(par = c(0.5, 2.5), fn = nd, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0.01,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
"